# Adding new glusterfs StorageClass to Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, glusterfs, kubernetes-helm

I set up GlusterFS storage on two VirtualBox VMs following a mixture of these two guides:

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/GlusterFSonCentOS

http://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Quick-Start-Guide/Quickstart/

The internal network has DHCP assigned IPs of 10.10.10.4 and 10.10.10.5. I've verified that the storage is working correctly and as expected.

At this point, I'm attempting to add a new StorageClass to Kubernetes using a YAML file, and the only resources I can find on the subject are relating to OpenShift specifically or Heketi GlusterFS.

I started creating the storage class as follows:

```
# storage-class.yml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gluster-container
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
parameters:
  resturl: "10.10.10.5"
```

I'm assuming this is incomplete but am unable to find more information about how to configure this. When I attempt to test with it, I get the following error:

```
ProvisioningFailed - Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gluster-container": create volume error: error creating volume Post 10.10.10.5/volumes: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

Anyone have any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: A while back one of my colleagues did make this work and wrote about it here, not sure if it helps you: http://blog.infracloud.io/gluster-heketi-kubernetes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GlusterFS provisioner in kubernetes wants to dynamically provision GlusterFS volumes - such as below:

```
gluster volume create glustervol1 replica 2 transport tcp 
gluster1.example.com:/bricks/brick1/brick \ 
gluster2.example.com:/bricks/brick1/brick.
```

GlusterFS in itself does not have an API endpoint to trigger the commands to create these volumes; however, the community has developed [Heketi](https://github.com/heketi/heketi) to be the API endpoint of GlusterFS. The RESTful management interface endpoint of Heketi is the value of `resturl` in your kubernetes `StorageClass`.

As @Vishal Biyani commented, http://blog.infracloud.io/gluster-heketi-kubernetes/ is a write-up on how to quickly get started with Heketi on GCP and connect that into kubernetes.

If the dynamic provisioning of GlusterFS volumes is not needed in your environment, you could use the NFS StorageClass and point to the load balancer in front of your GlusterFS. You would still get awesomeness of GlusterFS replication and distribution, but it would require you enable the NFS gluster service and manually create each gluster volume you want to expose to kubernetes.

Comment: The problem with that write-up is that it's specifically oriented towards a Google Cloud environment, which I do not have access to use.

Answer (score 0):

I created a script to manage the glusterFS volume-claims:

```
if [[ "$#" -le 3 ]]; then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "   $0 <operation> <namespace> <name> <size>"
  echo "   - operation: create | delete"
  exit
fi

OPERATION=$1
NAMESPACE=$2
NAME=$3
SIZE=$4

function create {
  gluster volume create $NAMESPACE-$NAME replica 3  server1:/mnt/gluster-storage/brick-$NAMESPACE-$NAME server2:/mnt/gluster-storage/brick-$NAMESPACE-$NAME server3:/mnt/gluster-storage/brick-$NAMESPACE-$NAME  
  gluster volume start $NAMESPACE-$NAME

  kubectl -n $NAMESPACE apply -f /etc/kubernetes/glusterfs-endpoints.yml
  kubectl -n $NAMESPACE apply -f /etc/kubernetes/glusterfs-service.yml

  cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: $NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: $SIZE
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  glusterfs:
    endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
    path: $NAMESPACE-$NAME
    readOnly: false
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  claimRef:
    namespace: $NAMESPACE
    name: $NAME
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: $NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
     requests:
       storage: $SIZE
EOF
}

function delete {
  kubectl -n $NAMESPACE delete pvc $NAME
  kubectl delete pv $NAME

  yes | gluster volume stop $NAMESPACE-$NAME
  echo
  yes | gluster volume delete $NAMESPACE-$NAME
  echo
  echo "#################################################################"
  echo "REMOVE BRICKS MANUALLY:"
  echo "  server1:/mnt/gluster-storage/brick-$NAMESPACE-$NAME"
  echo "  server2:/mnt/gluster-storage/brick-$NAMESPACE-$NAME"
  echo "  server3:/mnt/gluster-storage/brick-$NAMESPACE-$NAME"
  echo "#################################################################"
}

case $OPERATION in
  create)
    create
    ;;
  delete)
    delete
    ;;
esac
```

This creates the gluster volume and maps it to a volume claim in Kubernetes. So you can use glusterfs mounts without the need for automatic provisioning.

Make sure to run kubelet outside docker otherwise you'll be using an old version of gluster.fuse that misses a lot of the optimizations of the modern versions.